# Android - textview hash symbol not displayed properly

Tags: android, textview

In a text view i have to add a hash symbol before the textview. So , i did this .

```
textView.setText("#"+stringPlayerJerseyNumber);
```

result : 
[image]

Now i have tried using the string.xml file but there is no change.
Can any one help.
**NOTE** : I have created a custom text view class and then using that class as i have to modify the textview in my project.

Comment: maybe problem with encoding. or try Spannable

Comment: Problem with your font, typeface you are using in textview.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("&#35; "+stringPlayerJerseyNumber);
```